# Jwt token in dotnet with no Exp and default props

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I'am using .Net core 3.1 to make a indentity api that i register and make my user login , and with that i need to pass a JWT token for the frontend use.

I already generate my token with the claims i need, but i need the token to never expires (i know it's not a good practice but i'm just following orders), and also i need to remove token's default props such as nbf and iat.

I'm using the lib Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
I did not found much in the documentation, so i don't even know if it's possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting `ValidateLifetime` to `false` in `TokenValidationParameters`? That would allow any expiration dates.

Another thing you can do is to set `RequireExpirationTime` to `false`, which means `exp` doesn't need to be present in the token.

So, if you want to configure it to allow tokens not to contain an expiration time, but still validate the expiration time if the `exp` property is present, you can do this:

```csharp
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
    };
});
```

Also, if you want, you can set a custom lifetime validator at the same place:

```csharp
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // ... Other settings

        LifetimeValidator = (notBefore, expiration, token, parameters) =>
        {
            // Decide if expiration is valid. Don't forget about clock skew.
        }
    };
});
```

Although it's unclear if you have control over the token issuer, or the token consumer, or both. All the above solutions assume you have control over the token consumer.

If you have control only over the issuer, it's a bit more difficult. What comes to my mind is setting an `exp` date that is extremely far into the future. And for invalidating the tokens if it's later required, one thing you could do I suppose is to change the encryption key that the issuer and consumer uses to create/validate the signature.

#### Removing exp, iat and nbf at the issuer side

As for removing the properties from the token, you can just leave them our from the token generation. Assuming you're doing manual token generation, you'd want to configure it e.g. like this:

```csharp
var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: jwtIssuer,
    audience: jwtAudience,
    claims: new List<Claim>() {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
    },
    // 'expires' not set
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(someKey)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
);
```

Generating it this way it won't contain exp, iat or nbf (confirmed locally).

Of course if you happen to generate it via e.g. Identity Server, it's a different story, but then you forgot to mention that (you mentioned Identity, which is a membership system that doesn't have built-in JWT token generation capabilities).

Comment: I have controll of the issuer, and i guess your code will do for not check exp date, but i was asked to remove this from the token. Maybe because  if i set a far date on exp a malicious person coudl get a token and automaticly know the he has lifetime access. But thansk for the help, i guess just not check exp date will be enough.

Comment: So you don't have control over the token consumer? The problem is that if the consumer expects a valid expiration date in the token, that's pretty much the end of the story; the token simply needs to have that data. :/ But if you do have control over the consumer, then I think it's probably possible to configure it to check exp only if present.

Comment: As for invalidating the already issued tokens in this particular scenario, what first comes to my mind is to change the encryption key that the issuer and consumer uses for creating/validating the signature. Edit: Forgot to tag you, and not sure if you're notified without it :) @LincolnTeixeira

Comment: @LincolnTeixeira I added some stuff to the answer. But feel free to let me know what would help you the most, and what the details of your situation are, and I can edit it further. :)

Comment: thanks for the help man, i guess this will work for me. The part of Removing exp, iat and nbf at the issuer side it's what i really needed